# Is there a way to change the text size from net.minecraft.client.font.TextRenderer;

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I've tried changing the text size of the module buttons of my modmenu using matrixstack
but doesn't seems to work as it glitches out
the import im using:

net.minecraft.client.font.TextRenderer;

Theres any way to change the text size? because i've been looking for a solution and don't find anything

I tried:

changing the scales of the matrices
expecting to only change the text size

changed every x y z and also it bugged out, none value was useful.

Comment: Maybe a [mcve] will get you answers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem today and have solved it with a workaround, scaling the MatrixStack, rendering the text and rescaling the MatrixStack afterwards.

```
@Override
public void onHudRender(MatrixStack matrixStack, float tickDelta) {
   TextRenderer renderer = mc.getInstance().textRenderer;
       
   // i've scaled it by 8/10; so to rescale things i have to multiply by 10/8
   matrixStack.scale(0.8F, 0.8F, 0.8F); 
   renderer.draw(matrixStack, "Random txt", (int)(x *(10/8)) ,(int)(y *(10/8)), 0xffffff);
    matrixStack.scale(1.25F, 1.25F, 1.25F);
```